# tex4ht mathml output: how to get <mi>abc</mi> instead of <mi>a</mi><mi>b</mi><mi>c</mi>

Tags: tex4ht, mathml

tex4ht with mathml option generates `<mi>a</mi><mi>b</mi><mi>c</mi>` from `$abc$`. Is there a way to  get  `<mi>abc</mi>` output?

MWE (foo.tex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$abc$
\end{document}
```

tex4ht run `htlatex foo 'html,mathml'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to generate `<mi>abc</mi>`
 the latex input should be `\mathrm{abc}`

Comment: you are absolutely right. That's my ignorance of mathml. Mathml renders single char as italic and multi-characters are rendered as roman. To have multi-characters rendered as italic, I need to set `<mi mathvariant="italic">abc<mi> `, what I actually meant in my question. Now I see, my question is quite pointless, as setting `mathvariant` attribute does make sense to a sequence of characters, but does not make sense to a single character. Therefore, thank you for enlightening me and i accept you answer.

Comment: @deimi it's not just the mathml markup `$abc$` is incorrect TeX markup for a multiletter identifier: it is designed to use the math italic font and look like the implied product of three variables, `\mathit{abc}` on the other hand uses the text italic font and is designed to look like a single italic identifier (and makes a single mi in mathml)